# What is the python code equivalent of slicing a list in dart other than using the SUBLIST method?

Tags: python, flutter, list, dart, slice

I understand that the sublist method works similar to slicing, but what are some other ways i can get similar outputs?

For example

`List = [1,3,5,7,9]`

Python code
 `ListSliced = List[1:]`

Using sublist in dart
`ListSliced = List.sublist(1);`

Is there a equivalent of `List[1:]` in DART??

```
Code written in dart.

List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

branches(tree) {
  return tree.sublist(1);
}

isLeaf(tree) {
  return (!branches(tree));
}
```

```
Equivalent code in python.

def branches(tree):
        return tree[1:]

def is_leaf(tree):
        return not branches(tree)
```

Any ideas on whats causing this error

Full code for the tree program.

```
bool isTree(tree) {
  if ((tree is! List) | (tree.length < 1)) {
    return false;
  }
  for (final branch in branches(tree)) {
    if (!isTree(branch)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

branches(tree) {
  return tree.sublist(1);
}

Object label(tree) {
  return tree[0];
}

List tree(rootLabel, [List branches = const []]) {
  for (final branch in branches) {
    assert(isTree(branch));
  }
  return ([rootLabel] + branches);
}

isLeaf(tree) {
  return (!branches(tree));
}

var t = tree('hey', [
  tree('hello'),
  tree('hum', [tree('there'), tree('hey')])
]);
```

Comment: As you've already stated, the equivalent of `list[1:]` would be `list.sublist(1)`.  If that's not sufficient, please describe your requirements.  Perhaps the [`slice` extension](https://pub.dev/documentation/basics/latest/list_basics/ListBasics/slice.html) from `package:basics` does what you want.

Comment: @jamesdlin well i am trying to write a leaf function for this question i asked previously here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73783104/how-do-i-implement-this-python-tree-linked-list-code-in-dart It's not working the same as it did in python and i am figuring out where i'm going wrong.

Comment: @jamesdlin I tried using slice extension..I imported package:basics.dart and its saying unused import and slice extension is not working as intended.

Comment: `package:basics` has automated tests to ensure that it works.  The import line should be `import 'package:basics/basics.dart';`.  If that's not the problem, then you must have done something else wrong.  I can't tell you what without seeing what code you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use `skip`

For example:

```
List l = [1,3,5,7,9];
print(l.skip(2)); //prints (5,7,9)
```

Comment: hi, i updated my question with more details - If skip == sublist == [1:] i should be getting same results as i get in python, but when i run similar python code im getting errors,Can you please tell me where i'm wrong in my code?

Comment: @zram you can use the `!` operator only on booleans. I'm not familiar with python but I'm guessing it's a way to check if a list is empty? If so, replace `return (!branches(tree));` with `return branches(tree).isEmpty;`

Comment: Yes you are correct. The mistake i was doing was - when checking the tree , i was not calling the branches function hence running into errors, Once i called the branches function it worked as expected. Thanks a lot!